# Issue Drill querying S3 directories recursively

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-drill, amazon-aurora

I am trying to query a file under folder 't/atms-csv.csv' which I can successfully do it.

Query file directly with filename:

[image: Query file directly with filename]

There is another file in that location which as additional data from another day (both file columnmodel). when I try query recursively using folder name 't' which shows below error

Query file directory to scan all files:

[image: Query file directory to scan all files]

Tried queries (All doesnt worked out):

1. select * from `t/`;
2. select * from `/t/`;
3. select * from dfs.`t/`;
4. select * from dfs.`/t/`;
5. select * from fs.`t/`;
6. select * from fs.`/t/`;

I am using below versions,

Drill - 1.6.0

S3 protool: S3n (also tried S3, S3a)

Sample Query String:

```
{ "connection": "s3a://xxxxx-bucket", "config": { "fs.s3a.access.key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "fs.s3a.secret.key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }, "workspaces": { "root": { "location": "/", "writable": true, "defaultInputFormat": null } }
```